Is there another answer to the debate on Isaiah 53 who is the suffering servant Israel or Jesus that fits scripture
I found this debate fascinating and over 3 years of study I have a new theory that I can back up with scripture that solves both sides of the debate it's the only other story I can find that makes sense it's the only other story.

"another answer", other than what? What is "this debate"? ¶ The question needs to quote a specific scripture, explain what the conflict is, and summarize (or quote) the positions of the two sides. As it stands now, we have no idea what the question is talking about.

The debate on Isaiah 53 some think the suffering servant is Jesus some think it's Israel

That information should be in the question itself, not in a comment, which may eventually be deleted without warning. (When it is in the question, along with a more detailed explanation, then all of these comments will be deleted. The purpose of comments is to help improve postings. Eventually the good postings will have no comments.)

If the two usual answers are either Jesus or the nation of Israel (frequently called "my servant Jacob" in the Servant Songs of Isaiah), then another answer is King Hezekiah. The fact that Isaiah was his enthusiastic supporter is frequently cited in support of this idea. Also his prayer (2 Kings 19) saved Jerusalem and Judah from destruction after a course of personal suffering and affliction. It was Isaiah who confirmed that God had heard Hezekiah's prayer.
In the Talmud, Sanhedrin 94 gives much attention to God's intention to designate Hezekiah as the messiah, concluding that only his failure to sing of God as David did thwarted the plan. The great Rabbi Hillel was among those who thought the predictions about the messiah were fulfilled by Hezekiah (Sanh. 99). Hillel reportedly declared that no future messiah would come, because the prophecies were already fulfilled even though Hezekiah did not actually realize his potential.

Rabbi Hillel says: There is no Messiah coming for the Jewish people,
as they already ate from him, as all the prophecies relating to the
Messiah were already fulfilled, during the days of Hezekiah.

Our own Dick Harfield has suggested Zedekiah as another possible candidate:

Zedekiah, the last king of Judah, was indeed a man of sorrows. The
Babylonians killed his sons before his eyes, blinded him and led him
in chains to Babylon because he had rebelled against their rule. The
Servant Song refers to a Man of Sorrows whom I believe to be Zedekiah.
He was “wounded for our transgressions, he was bruised for our
iniquities” before he was taken in chains (“brought as a lamb to the
slaughter”) to prison in Babylon. The Servant was taken from prison
and cut off from the land of the living because of the transgressions
of the people... As their king, Zedekiah took responsibility for the
suffering of the people (“borne our griefs, and carried our
sorrows”)... Isaiah 53:3 tells us the Jews exiled with the man of
sorrows hid their faces from him and despised him, as they might do
with a king who had failed his nation.


@JohnMeredith Is there something I'm missing here in this discussion as it pertains to Isaiah 53? According to the Apostle Peter I believe nicely "sewed" up the identity of the person in Isaiah 53 at 1 Peter 2:21-25. Vs21 mentions Jesus Christ. Vs22, states Jesus was sinless. Vs23, Jesus was reviled while on that cross. Vs24, He bore are sins in His body on the cross and says by His wounds you are healed. This NOT talking about physical healing.  Verse 25 explains, For we were continually straying like sheep, but now you have returned to the Shepherd and Guardian of our souls.
